# How to use the Facebook API per Page rather than as one app

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I'm building an app that populates the database with Facebook posts, based on People that are in the database with a facebook page ID.  If a facebook page ID is found it pulls in their posts, and saves the posts that use a particular hashtag to the database.

My problem is, the Facebook API keeps timing out, and i've only got 4 or 5 people listed at the moment.  I see that you can get 250 requests per user, but i'm not sure i'm using the API in the correct way to get the posts per page.

Do I have to have the person login and personally give approval to do it this way?  That doesn't really work for what i'm trying to do.

I've been using the PHP SDK found on Github, below is my code.  I've been following it using the Graph Explorer, but one thing i'm not sure on is how to generate a token per page.

I'm currently using a manual token because i've no idea how to generate them per page, i've tried looking at the docs for both the Git PHP SDK, and also the Facebook API - and it's just not going in my brain, so i'm hoping somebody here might be able to spell it out to me a little better.

Thankyou for your help in advance, i'm a total newb to the Facebook API.

```
$apitoken = 'EAAF4azHPHh0BABSb7ZCPVv2U4pbBsZAfOMjA0tiTcKJoKKIsgfe0ZBZBf8ZAo5lZCHVh51WQzd1lvdOreA8Q4vU9F3ZCP9B1si1NWKZA7tiXxX1V06hNmQhT2tTZA8N27kinhiUDG0gDbYqLLZBZBRkGlAGuGdNZC3hdI6yJXLqd8QoPGWoi2LiLVmlqex2znHlbuqPzx0aq7YCVBQZDZD';


if( have_rows('social_networks') ): 
while( have_rows('social_networks') ): the_row(); 
if( have_rows('facebook_group') ): 
while( have_rows('facebook_group') ): the_row();
if(get_sub_field('facebook_username')){

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed
require_once 'src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '413876769201693',
'app_secret' => '1517da72a5c8ccaf5524d95a02d8481a',
'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
//'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);


try {
// Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
// If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
$username = $facebook_username;
$response = $fb->get("/$username?fields=fan_count,id,name,instagram_business_account,feed", "$apitoken");
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 // When validation fails or other local issues
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
 }


$me = $response->getGraphUser();
//print_r($me);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// FACEBOOK///////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$facebook_likes = $me['fan_count'];
$facebook_posts = $me['feed'];
} endwhile; endif; endwhile; endif;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// FACEBOOK POSTS ///////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////



foreach($facebook_posts as $facebook_post){
$facebook_post_id = $facebook_post['id'];

try {
// Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
// If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
$response = $fb->get("/$facebook_post_id?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions.limit(0).summary(true),message", "$apitoken");
 } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 // When Graph returns an error
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}


$facebook_post_details = $response->getGraphUser();

$facebook_post_message = $facebook_post_details['message'];
$facebook_post_likes = $facebook_post_details['likes']['summary']['total_count'];
$facebook_post_comments = $facebook_post_details['comments'];
$facebook_post_shares = $facebook_post_details['shares'];

$post_id_fb = get_the_ID();

 $args_fb = array( 
'post_type' => 'campaigns',
);
$the_query_fb = new WP_Query( $args_fb );

if ( $the_query_fb->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query_fb->have_posts() ) : $the_query_fb->the_post();
$campaign_id = get_the_ID();
$hashtag_fb = get_field('hashtag');
$post_title_fb = get_the_title(get_the_ID());

  if (strpos($facebook_post_message, $hashtag_fb) !== false) {
    if (get_page_by_title($facebook_post_message, OBJECT, 'campaign-posts')) {

  wp_update_post(array(
    'post_title'=> ' '.$facebook_post_message.' :facebook', 
    'post_type'=>'campaign-posts', 
    'post_content'=> $facebook_post_message,
    'status' => 'published',
    'meta_input' => array(
    'likes' => $facebook_post_likes,
     // 'shares' => $facebook_post_shares,
    //  'reactions' => $facebook_post_reactions,
      'influencer' => $post_id_fb,
      'hashtag' => $hashtag_fb,
      'platform'=> 'facebook',
      'link' => $facebook_username,            
    )

));

  wp_update_post(array(
    'post_title'=> $post_title_fb, 
    'post_type'=> 'campaigns', 
    'post_content'=> get_the_content($campaign_id),
    'status' => 'published',
    'meta_input' => array(
      'hashtag' => $hashtag_fb,
      )

    ));

    }else{
      wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title'=> ' '.$facebook_post_message.' :facebook', 
        'post_type'=>'campaign-posts', 
        'post_content'=> $facebook_post_message,
        'status' => 'published',
        'meta_input' => array(
        'likes' => $facebook_post_likes,
         // 'shares' => $facebook_post_shares,
        //  'reactions' => $facebook_post_reactions,
          'influencer' => $post_id_fb,
          'hashtag' => $hashtag_fb,
          'platform'=> 'facebook',
          'link' => $facebook_username,            
        )

    ));

    wp_update_post(array(
      'post_title'=> $post_title_fb, 
      'post_type'=> 'campaigns', 
      'post_content'=> get_the_content($campaign_id),
      'status' => 'published',
      'meta_input' => array(
        'hashtag' => $hashtag_fb,
        )

      ));

    }

} 

endwhile;
endif;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a page access token, someone with admin access to the page needs to grant your app access.

Comment: Is there any other way of gaining access to the page posts without timing the API out - without having to do this?

Comment: It is not “timing out”, you are running into the rate limits. So either get more active app users, or space your requests out over a longer period of time.